# script tables have one meaning

Tags: php

I am a newbie. Sorry for my bad English.

```
$release = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["release"]);
$numid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["numid"]);
$sql1 = mysql_query("UPDATE gg_cars SET release1='".$release."',numid='".$numid."' WHERE `avtor_id` = '".$_SESSION["id"]."' AND cat='1' ");
```

[image: such]

When user writes something in one row, all rows have the same meaning.

For example: If user writes in second row in "Release car to": John, and submits it, after refresh, all rows have written John in "release car to".

Comment: Not enough to give a definite answer but clearly the symptom points to your WHERE... clause in your query. Most likely the "`avtor_id`= '".$_SESSION['ID']."' - are the backquote round avtor_id necessary.? Also check the contents of $_SESSION. Try print_r($_SESSION);

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with this code:

1. It uses the old mysql methods instead of mysqli.
2. The where clause is using $_SESSION["id"] - which is a single value based on the session information instead of coming from the POST. This is the real cause of the submitted information being written to all rows.
3. Real escape string should be used on all variables being passed to the query.

Comment: I would need to see more of the HTML to know what you are calling the other inputs. You are most of the way there - you know that the avtor_id is the database key, you just need to know the name of the input field in the HTML that matches that. Then change $_SESSION["id"] to $_POST["id"] (assuming that's the name of the input). On the other hand, it may be that the ID field is blank - which is a whole other set of problems.